# Is there any tool or way to fail a build if there are unused namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

*Visual Studio* and *Resharper* highlight unused namespaces, but they **don't** generate any warnings so we couldn't use **Treat warnings as errors** and project compiles well:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for CI (continuous integration). You can use `Inspections in TeamCity`:

1. Create build step `Inspections (Resharper)`.
2. Add `Failure Conditions` `Fail build on metric change` (number of inspection warnings).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Detect_code_issues_in_a_build_using_ReSharper_and_TeamCity.html

Answer (score -1):

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) can show warnings in the sidebar but can be configured to show an error I think.

[StyleCop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop) might also be able to do this. Quick google search leads me to believe that `IDE0005` enables this.

Comment: I've already configured Resharper to show errors (you can see it on attached screenshot). My question was about how to fail build.

StyleCop doesn't work